# Android - How can I get rid of the BLACK BACKGROUND of a 3D object and see the camera view?

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, android-camera

I'm stuck in this problem. I have a **camera view** and an **opengl object** (cube).

I want to see the **3D object** while the **camera** is open. However, when I add two views (**openglview** and **cameraview**) if the object is on the top, it shows a black background (I can't see the camera view). If the camera is on the top, I can't see the cube....

Can someone help me?

in my Activity, I'm using this:

```
FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(this);
frame.addView(mMainGLView);
frame.addView(cameraPreview);
setContentView(frame);
```

But don't know why, the view that I added first is shown on the top. So here, the 3D Object is shown.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot overlay two Surface Views (at least prior to 3.0) - see the response from [Dianne on this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/08e7df2e96a7973d) -- essentially the z-ordering of SurfaceViews is not defined, so there is no way to tell one SurfaceView to be above another reliably.

Comment: Yes, alright, but I have the same question as there. how does one do augmented reality then ?

Comment: yup! i'm there, tying to understand if it takes a snapshot of the opengl view and adds it upto camera view, or not.